# How to make auto responsive when tilting on portrait and landscape?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a website that use **jaliswall.js** on it and I want to make it auto responsive on android tablet when user tilt it on portrait and landscape mode..

This is the css for **jaliswall.js** to make it responsive:

```
       .wall-column {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            width: 33.333333%;
            float: left;
            padding: 0 5px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        @media (max-width: 800px) {

            .wall-column {
                width: 50%;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 480px) {

            .wall-column {
                width: auto;
                float: none;
            }
        }
```

When I load the page in portrait mode, it looks okay (the item will shows 2 items per line):

[image]

But, if I tilt it to landscape mode, it will still shows 2 items instead of 3 items per line:

[image]

But, if I refresh the page, it will looks okay (the item will shows 3 items per line):

[image]

Btw my tab size is **800 x 1232 when portrait** and **1280 x 752 when landscape**..

My question is, how to make it auto responsive when I tilt it from portrait to landscape without refresh the page?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the resize event, either with `window.addEventListener('resize', function() { ... })` or with jQuery, `$(window).on('resize', function () { ... })`.

All you'll need to do in that function is to trigger a recalculation of the columns, which might require a little editing of the *jaliswall.js* script so that `init()` is available outside the IIFE. Alternatively, you could just trigger [a page reload using `location.reload()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp).

Answer (score 0):

It's **highly recommended** to use `display: flex;` (with all the vendor prefixes) for this kind of behaviour.

It's *perfect* for what you're trying to do.

Also, it's **mandatory** learning for css layouts nowadays.

Here's an **amazing** [post on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), highly recommended that you learn it.